# Присвоение строчкам массива id

Tags: java, android

Делаю приложение под android, которое смотря на id элемента ListView выводит определенный текстовый файл во второй активности. Проблема заключается в том, что когда я добавил поиск на главную активность при поиске не нужные элементы отсеиваются и на главном экране высвечивается нужный элемент, но при переходе на него открывается самый первый файл который бы соответствовал первому элементу ListView. Хотелось бы узнать можно ли как-то присвоить свои id элементам ListView, чтобы при "перемешивании" элементов текста не менялись

MainActivity

```
package com.example.arseny.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] items;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listView;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
        initList();

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.toString().equals("")){
                    initList();
                } else {
                    searchItem(s.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

        });

    }

    public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
        for(String item:items){
            String textToSearch1 = textToSearch.toLowerCase();

            if(!item.toLowerCase().contains(textToSearch1)){
                listItems.remove(item);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void initList() {
        items = new String[]{"1. ...",
                "2. ...",
                "3. ...",
                "4. ...",
                "5. ...",
                "6. ...",
                "7. ...",
                "8. ...",
        };
        listItems = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtitem, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Activity_Two.class);

                intent.putExtra("title", position);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

TwoActivity

```
package com.example.arseny.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class Activity_Two extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String resName = "n" + intent.getIntExtra("title", 0);
        Log.i("name", resName);
        Context context = getBaseContext();

        String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", "com.example.arseny.myapplication"));

        textView.setText(text);
    }

    @NonNull
    private String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId) {

        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

        InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();

        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.write(line);
                writer.append("\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй в качестве элементов списка не `String`, а класс с `id`

```
List items = new ArrayList<Item>(){{
    add(new Item(0, "..."));
    add(new Item(1, "..."));
    add(new Item(2, "..."));
    add(new Item(3, "..."));
    add(new Item(4, "..."));
}};

class Item {
    int id;
    String text;

    public Item (int id, String text) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

И почему ты заполняешь массив, а потом конвертируешь его в список? Работай сразу со списками, они удобнее и гибче.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Буду исправляться :)

Comment: @АрсенийГригорьев Если ответ помог, ставь галочку)

Comment: Начал переделывать, но возникли проблемы с внедрением кода. Как можно вставить код выше безошибочно?